# uwp FlipView Context Indicator as GridView is not recieving user interaction

Tags: xaml, gridview, uwp, user-interaction, flipview

I am using a **GridView** ( and I even tried ListView for this purpose ) as a context indicator of my FlipView. The **Problem** is that when I try to tap/click on a gridViewItem in order for it to get selected and hence changing the flipviewItem index as well, the gridview is not **recieving any tap or click** interaction by the user to change it. However when I change **flipviewItem** from directly flipview, it works as expected and gridview item selected is also changed accordingly.

**CODE**

```
<Grid>
    <FlipView x:Name="MainFlipView" ItemsSource="{x:Bind MyItemsSource}" Visibility="Visible"
              SelectionChanged="FlipChanged">
        <FlipView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="data:Video">
                <userControls:FlipDataTemplate />
            </DataTemplate>
        </FlipView.ItemTemplate>
    </FlipView>
    <GridView SelectionChanged="ContextChanged"
              Name="ContextIndicator"
              HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
              Margin="0,0,12,12"
              ItemsSource="{x:Bind MyItemsSource}">
        <GridView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="data:Video">
                <Image Width="40" Height="40" Source="{x:Bind Display}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemTemplate>
    </GridView>
</Grid>
```

**C#**

```
private void FlipChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    ContextIndicator.SelectedIndex = MainFlipView.SelectedIndex;
}
private void ContextChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    MainFlipView.SelectedIndex = ContextIndicator.SelectedIndex;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set `IsItemClickEnabled` to `True`  on your `GridView`.

Comment: I tried that and its still not working, but it should work even without it because I dont want to catch clicked event, I only want to change selection with user interaction like a normal listview or gridview does.

Comment: I just commented the FlipView in that piece of code ( which is actually a user control ) and now I am able to interact witht he gridview like it normally should work

Comment: Any chance your usercontrol is placed on top of your gridview?

Comment: No actually the xaml I posted above is a grid which has a flipview and also a gridview like you can see and that grid is wrapped in a usercontrol and I am using that user control on another page at the top for a header like scenario. and no flipview isnt on top because I can see the gridview clearly and also I tried changing gridview canvas.Zindex to 1 and that didnt help, only commenting out flipview helps

Comment: Try putting them inside a StackPanel instead of grid for testing. So we know they are definitely not overlapping.

Comment: yeah I just tried to put both of them in is different rows of same grid and now I can hover over gridview and also select Items normally,

Comment: But I want to put them in same row so that gridview can be overlay the flipview and be on bottom right corner of the flipview.

Comment: I was able to solve it , thanks a lot @JustinXL please see the answer I just posted :)

Comment: Glad to help. ;)

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve it with help of @JustinXL and I put FlipView and GridView in Rows and made RowSpan of FlipView to **2** so I got same UI as I wanted but now it works as expected, apparently if they are in same row then FlipView interferes with UI interaction on GridView.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <FlipView x:Name="MainFlipView" ItemsSource="{x:Bind MyItemsSource}" Visibility="Visible" Grid.RowSpan="2"
              SelectionChanged="FlipChanged">
        <FlipView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="data:Video">
                <userControls:FlipDataTemplate />
            </DataTemplate>
        </FlipView.ItemTemplate>
    </FlipView>
    <GridView SelectionChanged="ContextChanged" Grid.Row="1"
              Name="ContextIndicator"
              HorizontalAlignment="Right"
              VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
              Margin="0,0,12,8"
              Canvas.ZIndex="1"
              ItemsSource="{x:Bind MyItemsSource}">
        <GridView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="data:Video">
                <Image Width="40" Height="40" Source="{x:Bind Display}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemTemplate>
    </GridView>
</Grid>
```